# how to send different commands to multiple hosts to run programs in Linux

Tags: linux, r, ssh, openssh

I am an R user. I always run programs on multiple computers of campus. For example, I need to run 10 different programs. I need to open PuTTY 10 times to log into the 10 different computers. And submit each of programs to each of 10 computers (their OS is Linux). Is there a way to log in 10 different computers and send them command at same time? I use following command to submit program

```
nohup Rscript L_1_cc.R > L_1_sh.txt 

nohup Rscript L_2_cc.R > L_2_sh.txt

nohup Rscript L_3_cc.R > L_3_sh.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set up ssh so that you can login without entering a password (google for that if you don't know how). Then write a script to ssh to each remote host to run the command. Below is an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

host_list="host1 host2 host3 host4 host5 host6 host7 host8 host9 host10"

for h in $host_list
do
    case $h in
        host1)
            ssh $h nohup Rscript L_1_cc.R > L_1_sh.txt
            ;;
        host2)
            ssh $h nohup Rscript L_2_cc.R > L_2_sh.txt
            ;;
        esac
done
```

This is a very simplistic example. You can do much better than this (for example, you can put the ".R" and the ".txt" file names into a variable and use that rather than explicitly listing every option in the case).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use ssh in linux teminal to login different computers and send them different commands if I already logged in a linux by PuTTY?

Comment: Yes, just run the example script (after modification for your purposes). That is, put the above code in a file (e.g. my_run.sh) and then run ./my_run.sh from your putty session.

Comment: I do not know Linux very well. Can you change the for loop? Sometimes the program is not sequential. Can I change it as follows `if(h==mycomputer1.com) ssh $h nohup program_1.R >program_1_out.txt`;`if(h==mycomputer2.com) ssh $h nohup program_5.R >program_5_out.txt`

Comment: Sure you can. I have updated the answer to provide a very simplistic example. For a more advanced solution I suggest you do some beginner tutorials on Linux and shell scripting. That will get you much further in the long run than anyone giving you a full solution to this one problem.

Comment: `host_list="
c15-0330-02.ad.mtu.edu 
c15-0330-03.ad.mtu.edu 
c15-0330-04.ad.mtu.edu 
c15-0330-05.ad.mtu.edu 
c15-0330-06.ad.mtu.edu
"

for h in $host_list
do
    case $h in
        c15-0330-04.ad.mtu.edu)
            ssh $h nohup Rscript L_1.R > L_1_sh.txt
            ;;
        c15-0330-03.ad.mtu.edu)
            ssh $h nohup Rscript L_2.R > L_2_sh.txt
            ;;
        esac
done` I use put this in a file `test_2.sh`. But after I run it, it shows `: command not found:
'/test_2.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'/test_2.sh: line 10: `do

Answer (score 0):

Based on your topic tags I am assuming you are using ssh to log into the remote machines.  Hopefully the machine you are using is *nix based so you can use the following script.  If you are on Windows consider cygwin.

First, read this article to set up public key authentication on each remote target: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

This will prevent ssh from prompting you to input a password each time you log into every target.  You can then script the command execution on each target with something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#kill script if we throw an error code during execution
set -e

#define hosts 
hosts=( 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1)

#define associated user names for each host
users=( joe bob steve )

#counter to track iteration for correct user name
j=0

#iterate through each host and ssh into each with user@host combo
for i in ${hosts[*]}
do
  #modify ssh command string as necessary to get your script to execute properly
  #you could even add commands to transfer the file into which you seem to be dumping your results
  ssh ${users[$j]}@$i 'nohup Rscript L_1_cc.R > L_1_sh.txt'
  let "j=j+1"
done

#exit no error
exit 0
```

If you set up the public key authentication, you should just have to execute your script to make every remote host do their thing.  You could even look into loading the users/hosts data from file to avoid having to hard code that information into the arrays.